# Child component with muti-root nodes cannot be styled from parent scoped style

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

I need to style an entire component from another component where it is being used, in Vue 3 + Vite. I'm trying to set a class to the component tag but it just isn't working.

```html
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <HelloWorld class="hello"/>
</template>

<style scoped>
.hello {
  display: none;
}
<style>
```

*HelloWorld.vue*

```html
<template>
 <header></header>
 <main v-bind="$attrs"></main>
<template>
```

Comment: what is inside of HelloWorld component?

Comment: If you add any class to the component it will add to the root element of this component. please inspect and see whether the class is added or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If the `HelloWorld.vue` component has a single root element like:

```html
<template>
 <div class="hello-world">
   /* ... */
 </div>
</template>
```

your code should work without changing anything because the class `hello` will be added to `hello-world`. Read in the docs -> [Fallthrough Attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance)

#### If the `HelloWorld.vue` component has multiple root nodes like:

```html
<header>...</header>
<main>...</main>
<footer>...</footer>
```

then no "automatic attribute fallthrough behavior" will happen and you will have to manually bound the `$attrs` because otherwise you will get a warning:

```html
<header>...</header>
<main v-bind="$attrs">...</main>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Read in the docs -> [Attribute Inheritance on Multiple Root Nodes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes)

#### What is the problem with mutli-root components?

Once you add many root nodes to a component, then suddenly the parent cannot change the child element styling in `style scoped`.

[See it live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-3fvkzm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.vue&terminal=dev)

I don't know if this is the intended behavior or it's a bug, but if you want an update on this, [see this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5446)

#### Is there a way to style elements of a child mutli-root-nodes component?

One way is to use non-scoped `style`:

```
<style>
.hello {...}
</style>
```

Another way is to use `style module`:

```html
<template>
  <HelloWorld :class="$style.hello" />
</template>

<style module>
.hello {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

[See live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ysjezs?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev)

Comment: Thank you so much. Turns out I made an unbelievably dumb mistake. For testing purposes, I set display:none on my parent component's child element (which then had multiple root elements), and then went to my child component and changed it to have a single root. Now that it had a single root, the display:none worked and hid everything. I couldn't find out why it did this for the life of me. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of style in vueJS:

1. Global Style
2. Component base style

In the global style, you just need a css file in which all css is written and, on the other hand, you have the component base style if you want a style for the parent or the child you need.

**/deep**

Using this, you can easily target child elements:

```
<style>
/deep/{
  .childElement{
     display:none;

  }    
}    
<style>
```

I think this may help you. :)